# How to know when vert.x httpserver has actually started

Tags: groovy, vert.x

I'm embedding Vert.x into an application and I have the following code:

```
def vertx = Vertx.vertx()
def router = Router.router(vertx)

router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create())
// more routes here
vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router.&accept).listen(8080)
```

I'd like to be notified when the server is actually up and running / listening. I've been looking at the API and it would seem that I can use a ListenHandler, but can't seem to figure out what that looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a closure on the 2nd parameter of `listen`. This closure will take a `Future` which can access the `HttpServer` with `result()` :

```
vertx.createHttpServer()
  .requestHandler(router.&accept)
  .listen(8080, { f ->
    if (f.succeeded()) { ... }
  })
```

See: [Future](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Future.html)